# Reference inside sub equation to itself

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, subequations

Below is an example snippet of a proof in paper I am trying to reproduce. It seems. to be in a `subequation` environment, but it self references inside `intertext`.

How can I either self reference this, or continue the numbering? When I try using the functions above it gives me an error.

Thanks in advance

[image: Example Code]

Comment: \label and \ref can self reference easily, since they are created in one pass and used in the next.

Comment: Are you really using `\intertext`? I see no reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Just use them:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{16}
\begin{subequations}
  $H(\omega)$ satisfies the following two properties:
  \begin{align}
    & \lvert H(0) \rvert = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad h(n) = O(n^{-2})
      \text{ at infinity.}
      \label{eq:prop:1}
      \\
    & \lvert H(\omega) \rvert^{2} + \lvert H(\omega + \pi) \rvert^{2} = 1
      \text{ .}
      \label{eq:prop:2}
  \end{align}
  Conversely let $H(\omega)$ be a Fourier series satisfying \eqref{eq:prop:1}
  and \eqref{eq:prop:2} and such that
  \begin{equation}
    \lvert H(\omega) \rvert \neq 0 \quad\text{for}\quad \omega\in[0,\pi/2]\text{
      .}
  \end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]